# How to add an 'opApply' on primitive types in D?

Tags: foreach, operator-overloading, d

I've been trying to foreach through a character array in D but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

```
public MyClass opApply(MyClass delegate(int[]) dg) {
    // ...
    return myClass;
}

foreach(MyClass a; [5,6,9,2]) {}
```

Comment: "Of course this" what? `foreach` over arrays should work by itself in D.

Comment: @CyberShadow I've no idea what I was pointing out there, it must've been cut off. Also, I can figure out how to add another foreach handler for these arrays, for example return a MyClass object for every integer in the array.

Comment: Because the question, as written, doesn't even make sense and therefor is unanswerable.

Comment: A helper that returns an input range is probably what he needs. Then `foreach(item; my_string.my_view)` would work.

Comment: @BCS I added an example, is it clear now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do what you want in the example precisely, but you can create a helper method/wrapper object to do almost the same thing.

So the result would be:

```
foreach(MyClass a; [5,6,9,2].byMyClass) {}
```

The `byMyClass` function would look something like this:

```
MyClassRange byMyClass(int[] array) {
      return MyClassRange(array);
}
```

`MyClassRange` is a helper object which provides the iteration:

```
struct MyClassRange {
      int[] array;
      this(int[] a) { array = a; }

      import std.array;

      bool empty() { return array.empty; }
      void popFront() { array.popFront; }
      MyClass front() { return new MyClass(array.front); }
}
```

Then, that thing can be used with `foreach`. For this exact example btw you could also just use `foreach(MyClass c; [1,2,3].map!(a => new MyClass(a)))`. The `map` function is found in `std.algorithm`.